# How do I add an ID attribute to each named tuple create from a CSV file?

Tags: python, csv

I'm pulling stock-quotes from Yahoo into a named tuple using the CSV module.

```
YahooQuote = collections.namedtuple(
    'YahooQuote', 'date, open, high, low, close, volume, adj_close')

def prices(ticker):
    # make url given ticker
    csvfile = urllib2.urlopen(url) 
    return map(YahooQuote._make, csv.reader(csvfile))
```

Yahoo's stock quote csv format does not include the stock ticker. If I adjusted my named tuple class to include a `ticker` attribute, how would I modify the `map` expression to make it add the value of the `ticker` argument to each of the named tuple instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm genetically incapable of understanding code with map() in it, so I'm just going to transform "map(f, i)" into "[f(x) for x in i]" so I don't have to:

```
return [YahooQuote._make(x) for x in csv.reader(csvfile)]
```

Then it's a simple matter to add ticker to the end of the lists returned by csv.reader:

```
YahooQuote = collections.namedtuple(
    'YahooQuote', 'date, open, high, low, close, volume, adj_close, ticker')

def prices(ticker):
    # make url given ticker
    ticker_list = [ticker]
    csvfile = urllib2.urlopen(url) 
    return [YahooQuote._make(x + ticker_list) for x in csv.reader(csvfile)]
```

Comment: Beautiful. I too would rather use list comprehension. Stupid of me to stick too close to the `namedtuple` docs.